# Send email with attachment in Java via relay mail server error

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am running a Java web application and send email. "mail.smtp.auth: false" in props, but I still keep getting

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

What is the best solution? I couldn't find what I was looking for in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291412/send-email-in-java-via-relay-server/75180912#75180912)

```yaml
properties:
      mail.smtp.auth: false
      mail.smtp.starttls.enable: false
      mail.debug: true
      mail.host: xx.xx.xx.x
      mail.port: 25
      mail.smtp.socketFactory.class: xxxxxx
```

This is how I edited my settings. But I'm getting authentication error.

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Comment: It sounds like the mail server you're using requires authentication. You will need to authenticate.

Comment: Why is the attachment in the caption important? Can you send e-mails w/o attachments?

Comment: attachment is very important. Okey i want to authenticate

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]?